# Having Trouble Configuring Tomcat 9 with Eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

So I installed Apache Tomcat 9 on my computer, and am having trouble configuring and running it on Eclipse Photon. When I start the server through the Monitor Tomcat application, I can open it up to see the appropriate Apache Tomcat Page, however when I try to run it through eclipse, I get an Error 404, as shown on this image:

[image]

I tried changing the server location from "use workspace metadata" to "use tomcat installation", as I saw on several websites and videos to correct the exact issue I'm having ("The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."), but when I run the file after saving that configuration, I get the error as shown in this image:

[image]

I am not attaching an application to it just yet, I wanted to ensure that the server was running, and I could see the appropriate Apache Tomcat splash page when I try to access localhost:8080, but that isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

The Monitor Tomcat application deploys a root application to handle '/'. When Eclipse launches Tomcat for you, it does not deploy anything you do not explicitly tell it to, so nothing's there for '/'.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#If_I_start_my_Tomcat_server_and_try_to_display_Tomcat.27s_default_page.2C_why_do_I_see_a_directory_listing_or_404_error_page.3F

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, I discovered that the reason I was receiving those errors was because the entire Tomcat 9.0 file had restricted access, only administrator-level accounts could modify those files. I was able to resolve the issue by going into the file path, right-clicking on the "Tomcat 9.0" folder --> Properties --> Security --> Edit --> Users --> Full Control.